# RHEL MarkLogic 9.0-6.2 not including Schematron?

Tags: marklogic, schematron, marklogic-9

The docs at http://docs.marklogic.com/schematron suggest that the Schematron API be imported via `"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/schematron" at "/MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy"`

On RHEL ML 9.0-6.2, `/MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy` does not appear to be part of the deployed product (verified on fs) and consequently gives an `XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) Module /MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy not found` when trying to `import module namespace schematron = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/schematron" at "/MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy";`

Has Schematron support been isolated as part of an optional package, or is this an oversight in the 9.0-6.2 RHEL release?

EDIT: xquery test case (e.g., from qconsole)

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace schematron = "http://marklogic.com/schematron" at "/MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy";

"this should pass for xquery anywhere"
```

response:

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) Module /MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy not found
```

Comment: In my Ubuntu installation i can find it in `/opt/MarkLogic/Modules/MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy`. Might be the same in RHEL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `9.0-7` this works for me:

```
import module namespace schematron = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/schematron"
            at "/MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy";

"this should pass for xquery anywhere"
```

Notice how i import the namespace `"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/schematron"` including a `xdmp` which you do not.

The [documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/schematron) seems to be wrong in this case.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. Will re-test with 9.0-6.2 and 9.0-7 builds this week and accept answer once tested. Will double-check on documentation (I got the same impression) and report back so ML can take action if needed.

Comment: I just noticed i get the same error like you in my `9.0-4` installation. So this might actually be fixed in the `9.0-7` release. I could not find a note about that in the release notes (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes) though.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. Accepted answer.